# Failed to install Visual Studio Express 2012 of Web

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installation

I tried to install the Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web [officially downloaded](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2012-express) from Microsoft but I got the error as below snapshot.

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate SP1

What is the work around for that?

[image]